# Android and JSP Communication Error

Tags: android, apache, jsp, http

I Have this JSP which just check the `username` and `password` and `"out.write"` `1` or `0` based on `true` or `false.`

```
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>    
    <%
        if(request.getParameter("username").equals("anas") && request.getParameter("password").equals("azeem"))
        {
            out.write("1");

        }
        else
            out.write("0");
    %> </br>
```

Now my android code is somerhing like this

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agent_login);

        edit_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_username);
        edit_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { // must add this code in
                            // order not to get the
                            // Exception while executing
                            // program
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                username = edit_username.getText().toString();
                password = edit_password.getText().toString();

                Log.d(TAG, "Username:" + username);
                Log.d(TAG, "Password:" + password);

                try {
                    new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/MyApp/login.jsp");
                                List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",edit_username.getText().toString()));
                                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",edit_password.getText().toString()));
                                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                                Log.d("xml", ""+xml.length());   //To confirm anything is there in the "xml"
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }.start();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("xml", xml.toString());
                    Log.d("Server", e.toString());
                }

                try {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(xml.charAt(10))) == 1) {  //****HERE*******
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LoginSuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Agent_Login.this,AgentHome.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        edit_password.setText("");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Now on HERE (in comment) there gives a `NullPointerException`, which is I think because the `xml` is empty.

So, my question is how can I get the reply from the JSP in Android. I tested it on PC with an HTML form and its working absolutely fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. A varaible is named `xml` but it will probably not contain any XML, as far is I can see; you're returning HTML.
2. Why would the `1` be located at position 10 in the returned string?
3. You're logging the content of `xml`; what is its value?

Comment: First I must say that xml is a String variable at class level.

Comment: First I must say that "xml" is a String variable at class level. A friend was using similar code and it was returning something like 

<html>1</html> or the 0 case istead of 1.

That Log code doesn't run at all.

Comment: @AnasAzeem You should look at JSON and use a JSON parser. Relying on the web server's response format in this hard-coded way is doomed to fail. Also, if you don't know what the content of `xml` is, just add a log call for it and look at it.

Comment: The xml is always Null, the code which logs it is never executed.

Can you suggest some JSON tutorials, I know nothing about it. THANKS

Comment: It's about time you add some log calls to see what goes wrong. Does the code even connect successfully to your page?

Comment: It indeed is connecting to jsp, because in that jsp itself there is a code to create a txt file with username and password inside. That file is always created whenever the condition of username and password is satisfied. Can  sumbudy tell me how to get data form JSP in android.</b>